# print() always returns 1, is there a practical use?

Tags: php

The command echo does not return anything. But print returns 1. Always. **What is the practical use of this returning 1?** Sure it can be used in an expression, but **isn't the expression useless if it is always true** and cause use of more code?

```
<?php
unset($empty);
if(print ($empty)){
    echo "Yep sure thing. Print strikes again with a ", "1.";
}
?>
```

Shouldn't it always return the same result as below, so what's the point then?

```
<?php
print ($empty);
echo "Yep sure thing. Print strikes again with a ", "1.";
?>
```

This question is about the returning 1 and not that "Echo allows echoing more than one string separated by commas while print doesn't" etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`print` always returns one in the real world. If you are trying to perform Inception, you can devise a `print` function that always returns zero. That way, you can check to see if you are in a dream or the real world.

In reality however, the usage of `print`'s return value is the same as simply using `true`. Infinite while loops, printing debugging information, etc. are all very compelling uses but they are *bad design* (verging on insane) and should be avoided.

Comment: haha i don't know if this answer got voted up for the advice on how to program an inception...or a practical us for the function thats totally not a good idea to do ! but still + 1

Answer (score 2):

Since the result is always truthy, you can chain it together in an expression like this:

```
if (print('debug stuff') && $a == 1) {
    // do stuff
} elseif (print('debug another') && $a > 56) {
    // do stuff
}
```

As the conditions are evaluated it would work like a kind of debug that doesn't influence the outcome.

Or, used in an infinite loop:

```
while(print('still in the loop')) {
    // do something very exciting
}
```

Although these are some things you couldn't do with `echo` (it would cause a parse error), the usefulness of it is basically confined to the **testing and debugging** stage rather than the operational stage.

Comment: Thanks... It is really obvious. You may even print there some loop variables.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot see any usefull expressions. But i can create some strange:

For loop short printer:

```
for($i=0; $i<100; $i+=print($i.')<br/>')) ;
```

While loop print counter:

```
//$result is some db result
$rowCounter = 0;
while($row = $result->fetchAssoc()) {
    $rowCounter += print($row['column']);
}
```

Comment: Cool, I like the examples. Especially the for loop. Normally I would do that one in two rows. I wonder if it's smart to use or if it would be wiser to use other code for the same result.

Answer (score 0):

```
**echo**

No return value
Outputs one or more strings separated by commas

  e.g. echo "String 1", "String 2"

**print**

Returns 1, so it can be used in an expression
Outputs only a single string
```

e.g. if ((print "foo") && (print "bar"))