# Which kind of purpose was for returning 1 in print from PHP lenguage?

Tags: php

Could you explain why 'print' in PHP return 1?

For what? Was it the result of simple creativity? Or maybe, "we have created, and you can do with that whatever you wish"?

For example,

```php
$a = print('4');
var_dump($a);
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? What do you expect `$a` to contain? Maybe question should be dup of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16709267/print-always-returns-1-is-there-a-practical-use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs

> Returns 1, always.

**Why Should I use print? What kind of Advantage?**

Both `print` and `echo` are language constructs and `echo` is even faster than `print`. But the advantage of `print` is that it is more flexible than echo and it can do anything that echo can do.

The simplest example is, `print` can be used in an expression like ternary.

```php
($someValue) ? print('somevalue is True') : print('someValue is false');
```

This is because as I stated above `print always returns 1` and `echo doesn't have a return value`.

Read Official Documentation Here:

[PHP print](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.print.php)

[PHP echo](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php)